# Registering a mongoose schema-model globally without exporting?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

I have read in various other posts that it is possible to register a mongoose model without exporting directly from the Schema by using:

```
mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema)
```

In this example, Person would become globally to any files in the project that `require('mongoose')` 
However I'm unable to get this to work and am resorting to exporting from the schema file and importing where it is required. Although this is not a big problem, I am curious as to why examples show this variation, which I am unable to get working. The error I get is:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/seeList net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

To be clear, my schema looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    age: {type: Number, required:false}
})


mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

And the variables declared in the file which needs access to the `Person` are:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

By simply adding to these variables:

```
var Person = require('../models/personSchema')
```

And by adding to the exporting schema file's

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

It will work fine. But why do I need these additional lines if the model is supposed to be globally available?

Comment: The model can be accessed globally by using `mongoose.model('Person')`, not `mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema)`.